# How to check if helper method/variable exists in rspec?

Tags: authlogic, rspec2

Im still trying to figure out rspec and right now I am using authlogic to handle my users and sessions. I did the usual authlogic stuff like adding the def current_user method to applciation controller, and as a helper method, but how do I access that in my rspec controller file?

Here is my user_sessions_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'authlogic'

describe UserSessionsController do

  context "user is already logged in" do

    before(:each) do
      include Authlogic::TestCase
      activate_authlogic
      UserSession.create Factory.build(:user)
    end

    it "should redirect the user to the home page" do
      get 'new'
      response.should redirect_to(home_path)
    end

  end

  describe "#create" do
    context "when the user is not logged in" do    
      before(:each) do
        current_user = nil
      end

      it "correct authorization should create a new session" do
        post 'create', {:login => "afactoryuser", :password => "apass", :password_confirmation => "apass"}
        current_user.should_not be_nil
      end
    end
  end

end
```

when i run rspec it just tells me:

```
correct authorization should create a new session
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x000001017d3410>
```

so im guessing it is in the rspec context...but how do i know it should be in user-sessions_controller? And am I even testing it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insted of current_user in your RSpec, try `controller.current_user`

If you want to stub current_user method use: `controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(whatever)` in `before :each`
 block, but then you will always get `whatever` if you stub it.